# Apache jMeter erroring out with high load requests - java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: apache, jmeter

I'm struggling with using jMeter to test my .NET web app.  I'm running jMeter locally against a staging environment in Azure for my app.  Hitting some endpoints, I get:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Which tells me it's something happening on my end, not caused by my app.  My app shows no errors and is serving requests at this magnitude with ease.

In this particular test, I have 300 threads with a ramp-up of 10 seconds, repeated 3 times.

What can I do to diagnose further?  Is there some kind of limit being imposed client-side?

Comment: 1. are you able to run 1, 10, 100 threads successfully before running 300? 2. Does this error happen for all requests, or just some?

Comment: @KirilS.yes, yes, yes.  Just some.

Comment: In such case it's possible that your test is exhausting available ports, causing client to wait for port, and sometimes timing out. You can confirm that by running 150+150 clients from 2 JMeter hosts. If that works, it's even more likely. If you are on windows, start from doing registry changes this article suggests (esp. related to TIME_WAIT): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx (it's about biztalk, but really it applies to any other port exhaustion). On Linux similar process is described here: http://www.lognormal.com/blog/2012/09/27/linux-tcpip-tuning/.

Comment: Thank you @KirilS.

Answer (score 1):

JMeter default configuration is not suitable for producing high loads, you may use it for tests development and debugging only. When it comes to running the load test you need to increase at least [Java Heap Space](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/java-heap-space-memory-size-jvm.html) allocated to JMeter (it is only 512Mb by default, I think browser which you're using to read this page consumes twice as more).

You should be also running your test in [non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) as JMeter GUI is not designed to correctly display information when more or less immense load is being generated, you can use it up to ~50 threads maybe.

More information:

- [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#best_practices)
- [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

---

I would also suggest keeping an eye on your load generator health during the test and collect information regarding CPU, RAM, Swap, Disk, Network usage as well as some JVM metrics like Heap usage, Garbage collections, etc. so you could see whether your JMeter instance is configured good enough, if there is enough headroom w.r.t. hadrware resources, etc. Of course doing it on server side is a must. You can use [PerfMon JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) to collect this information and plot results along with other test metrics so you could correlate the values and identify the cause. See [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) for plugin configuration and usage instructions